# How to fix LD_PRELOAD?

Tags: debian

I changed the LD_PRELOAD and now,  I can't do anything, such as connecting to SSH or using ls,cp,mv and so on, it's show me :

```
ls: error while loading shared libraries: librt.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

what I've done, I moved these below files from `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` to `/root` and then wrote this :

```
LD_PRELOAD=/root/libc-2.19.so:/root/libdl-2.19.so:/root/libm-2.19.so:/root/libpthread-2.19.so:/root/librt-2.19.so bash
```

but now, I can't undo my job, any idea ?

Comment: Install a live system on an USB stick, boot it, mount disks somewhere, move files back, undo any changes related to `LD_PRELOAD`, boot from disk, and hope it actually works.

Comment: I don't have access to my system, right now I just have a live ssh session :(

Comment: Where did you write this command? Do I understand correctly that you successfully ran a shell with these settings, but then new shell instances won't work because you moved the libraries to a nonstandard location?

Comment: yes, exactly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing parts of the libraries. For example in your first error message, `ls` needs `librt.so.1`. It can find this as a symbolic link, but you've moved the target of the symbolic link into `/root` so it fails. Here's an example of what you should have:

```
ls -l /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 31744 Dec  4  2016 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.24.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    13 Dec  4  2016 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 -> librt-2.24.so
```

If you still have a `root` shell you can try copying the libraries back again. You'll need this alias:

```
mcp() { src="$1" dst="$2"; test -f "$src" || return 1; while :; do read -N 10240 -r data; test -z "$data" && break; echo -n "$data"; done <"$src" >"$dst"; }
```

And here's how you'd attempt the fix:

```
cd /root
for lib in lib*.so; do mcp "$lib" /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/"$lib"; done
```

Unset your `LD_PRELOAD` and see if you've recovered.

Failing that you WILL need to restore from a rescue CD. Or reinstall.